# GRPC server fails to launch (greeter server example)

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

Installed GRPC (C++) according to the installation docs (https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/cpp/). The build went through successfully. However, after building and executing the helloworld example (`examples/cpp/helloworld/`), the `greeter_server` hangs. Log below:

```
GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG ./greeter_server      
D1116 13:26:27.355365283    6807 ev_posix.cc:174]            Using polling engine: epollex
D1116 13:26:27.355788088    6807 dns_resolver_ares.cc:503]   Using ares dns resolver
```

The expected behavior would be for the `greeter_client` to display `Greeter received: Hello world`.

After building with debug info, running with GDB, and getting a thread dump:

```
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fffeffff700 (LWP 2561)):
#0  futex_wait_cancelable (private=0, expected=0, futex_word=0x55555559cef0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
#1  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, mutex=0x55555559ce90, cond=0x55555559cec8) at pthread_cond_wait.c:502
#2  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x55555559cec8, mutex=0x55555559ce90) at pthread_cond_wait.c:655
#3  0x00007ffff7daf392 in gpr_cv_wait () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc.so.9
#4  0x00007ffff7f27930 in grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff7db0ed3 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc.so.9
#6  0x00007ffff701cfa3 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#7  0x00007ffff71404cf in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7ffff6e81700 (LWP 2560)):
#0  futex_wait_cancelable (private=0, expected=0, futex_word=0x5555555a0e20) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
#1  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, mutex=0x5555555a0dc0, cond=0x5555555a0df8) at pthread_cond_wait.c:502
#2  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x5555555a0df8, mutex=0x5555555a0dc0) at pthread_cond_wait.c:655
#3  0x00007ffff7daf392 in gpr_cv_wait () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc.so.9
#4  0x00007ffff7f27930 in grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff7db0ed3 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc.so.9
#6  0x00007ffff701cfa3 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#7  0x00007ffff71404cf in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff6e84cc0 (LWP 2554)):
#0  __strcmp_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-avx2.S:737
#1  0x00007ffff7f5aaac in grpc_core::TraceFlagList::Set(char const*, bool) () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff7f5abbe in grpc_tracer_init() () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff7cc9361 in grpc_init () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc.so.9
#4  0x0000555555564e36 in grpc::GrpcLibraryCodegen::GrpcLibraryCodegen (this=0x55555559bd30, call_grpc_init=true) at /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:45
#5  0x00007ffff7edf49e in grpc_impl::ServerBuilder::BuildAndStart() () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
#6  0x0000555555575c29 in RunServer () at greeter_server.cc:61
#7  0x0000555555575d7d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdb78) at greeter_server.cc:71
```

Comment: @rustyx expect the server to listen for connections (after printing `Server listening on`). isolated the problem to the `builder.BuildAndStart()` function (server blocks during the execution of this) [source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_server.cc#L60)

Comment: looks like this is an open issue: [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21213)

Comment: fixed! looks like there was an issue with multiple versions of libgrpc being present. cleared them and did a fresh install. current installation appears to be functional

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you dont link the library grpc_unsecure along with other grpc libs..

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20757#issuecomment-545773014

Comment: Can you put the information in this post? The link may go dead in the future, but the info may still be relevant to some users.